# 301 Redirect from subdomain to URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a 301 redirect from a subdomain to a facebook page. I'm using this below and have uploaded it to the root folder on the server.  I've also tried to upload this to the subfolder (example.com/blog), but to no avail...

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.co.uk
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.facebook.com/example/$1 [R=301,L]

    #Deny access to htaccess
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance,

Ash

**NOTE:**
I've investigated this a little further and forgot to mention that the subdomain is set up on an old version of Drupal. This causes the site to fail when we set up any subdomain.

We can still navigate to the folder that the subdomain uses and the redirect works fine there.

So, the issue seems to be with drupal and subdomains, not the redirect.

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting?

This bit of code would deny access to everything, not just .htaccess like it states in the comments...

```
#Deny access to htaccess
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```